# Knocking the short wall down on the cupboard under the stairs

Tags: drywall, walls, doors

I'm looking for some advice about whether I can take some studwork down to create a door.

[image]We want to create a narrow door on the cupboard under the stairs on the short edge. Currently it's a small door on the long edge.

[image]I've taken some of the inside plasterboard off. Is there any chance this wall bears load and the central horizontal beams cannot be removed? I will be leaving the long wall and as much studwork and possible in place.

[image]You can see the top of the staircase in question and also the above staircase which seems to be self supporting. That and the general flimsiness of this wall makes me think this will be fine.

Comment: That stud spacing in the 2nd pic (where you removed the drywall) looks more than 16" o/c.  If so, I'd be willing to bet money that's not a load-bearing wall.

Comment: It is close to 16". Thanks!

Comment: Would you be cutting either of the studs to install your new door?

Comment: I'm going to attempt to use a narrow door and not touch the vertical studs. Sadly it's a next weekend or later job now thanks to some waterworks 

Comment: Then you should have no structural issue simply knocking out that drywall.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the stairs are supported by the flimsy wood in the cupboard. They would need more than that, and are probably self supporting, and attached to the main floor support beams.

You should be safe, but if in doubt ask someone else. I would demolish or do whatever with that cupboard. You would need to leave some support for blocking the old door, and the door frame will support the other side... Although you may need to find the supports for the wall above your new door, to stop it falling down completely, not the stairs, the upper part of the wall.